# Как сравнивать/отнимать/прибавлять даты?

Tags: дата, php, datetime

Добрый день!

Есть фильтр - показывать зарегистрированных пользователей за 5 минут/1 час/1 день/1 месяц/1 год. В базе есть дата регистрации.

Как мне вывести данные по фильтру?
Спасибо большое.

Comment: А при чем здесь PHP? Посылайте дату в запрос в базу и вытаскивайте 

    WHERE register_date > NOW() - INTERVAL "здесь цифра из фильтра" MINUTE/HOUR/DAY/WEEK/MONTH

http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Может быть переводить их в UNIX формат функцией `strtotime`, сравнивать, отнимать и т.д, а потом вновь переводить в привычный Вам формат.

Не забывайте, что в UNIX используются секунды

Answer (score 0):

Расширения для работы с датой и временем  http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.calendar.php  Но в вашем случае лучше и работать в БД